# Is there a way to kill charged enemy soldiers without the REC?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

In Batman: Arkham Knight, is there a way to defeat soldiers without having the REC gun? I got to the part where

> the Cloudburst explodes the city with the gas.

Comment: What do you mean by "charged" soldiers? The ones that carry stun batons that shock you if you punch them? Just jump behind them and immediately strike them in the back.

Comment: But Batman doesn't kill...?

Comment: Oh Ben... Don't I see you everywhere?                                                                            @Nolonar I mean the ones who get shocked by the medics. You know after the spoiler and to the next airship?

Comment: Ah, yes. *Those* charged soldiers. I completely forgot they even existed. @Katana314's answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the soldiers that the medics have electrified? You should be able to shut off the electrificiation with the batclaw. (left trigger + Y, or triangle) Yeah, it's not a very logical effect, but maybe Batman once accidentally clawed a power line, and so he implemented some kind of electrical grounding in the batclaw.

Comment: That's the way you discharge them... though I don't remember ever hearing that the REC can discharge them. I don't think that ever worked. I don't think they'd put an enemy type that cannot be defeated without required items, seeing as how REC is optional.